# Connected App / Canvas in Managed Package with dynamic endpoint

Tags: managed-package, integration, connected-apps, oauth, canvas

I am selling a Java App that customers are installing on their server and now build a Salesforce app (Managed package) to integrate it. This means

- The Salesforce App packages some **Canvas** elements to render UI from the Java app
- The Java App needs to modify Salesforce data on behalf of the Salesforce User who triggered it through the Canvas-exposed UI. I planned on using packaging a **Connected App** for that.

[image]

I am struggling with those questions:

**1) How to cope with dynamic Canvas endpoints**

The problem is that Connected Apps and Canvas need predefined Endpoint URLs and I don't have them during package time. The Java app of one customer mights sit on www.acme.com and the next one on www.customer.com.

**2) Will the Modifications made by the Java app through the Connected App be on behalf of the actual user?**

This is what I want. If the Salesforce User clicks a button int Java UI displayed throught the Canvas and the Java app then uses a Salesforce API to modify data in Salesforce will this be some kind of super admin who does it or the actual user. Will it respect permissions and profiles?

**3) What are the drawbacks of such an architecture compared to both systems having real REST APIs and each other just calling each others APIs.**

Comment: I feel this might be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're currently stuck on a path that is likely a non-starter. I would think the Java app should be a Static Resource (hosted in Salesforce), with configurable REST API endpoints.

Comment: You are following me and have seen my attempts. :-( The reason for asking about potential solution details is that naming the business reasons behind it are even more vague. No time to provide a stable API on Java side. No time to recreate nice UI in Salesforce. The cheapest and fastest integration you can get which still passes Security Review. I was to shy to ask this...

Comment: BTW: I absolutely dont get what you mean with "the Java app should be a static resource in Salesforce". It's a Java WAR that customers install on their Tomcat in their datacenter. So the Canvas would have to connect to "www.UNKNOWN.com/myknownsubpath

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying it was client-side Java (e.g. an applet). What your saying makes more sense now. I don't see any way you can write a packageable canvas app, nor pass a security review, since each client has their own server. I think you'd need to have at least some sort of basic API for your clients to install instead, and you'd host the central app on your server(s).